# FX Options Greeks: Is there a meaning in converting the sensitivities values in different currencies?

Tags: options, fx, greeks, currency

Suppose you have a Call on JPY, domestic currency is USD
The price will be in USD
Let's say delta = 0.93

Does it make sense for any reporting reasons to convert this value into JPY ?
What is even the unit of a Delta in case of FX options?
(of course I understand, here in the sample above, a 1 unit movement in the underlying price will induce a 0.93$ movement in the price.)

Comment: Is it not simply the change in the value of your position in currency xyz for the relevant change in the derivative?

Comment: I am still not convinced by what you imply. We need to use currency rates corresponding to foreign and domestic currencies when using the closed-form formula. So the price of a USD/EUR option wouldn't be as simply as converting the price of a JPY/EUR option, using the JPY/USD rate.